# Major revision submission time for IEEE Access

Tags: ieee

I received a major revision for IEEE Access article. How much time exactly do I have to submit the revised version. Nor the FAQs doesnt mention any, nor the email by the editor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no deadline nor any notion of 'major revision' as per other journals.  All articles that require revision are 'rejected'.  Authors can then resubmit their article as 'new'.  If it is an actual reject, the corresponding Decision email will state that no resubmission is allowed.

Authors can reference the identifier of their previous manuscript to ensure the same editor, and hopefully reviewers, process their manuscript.

Comment: Resubmission is allowed in my case

Answer (score 0):

I was once in a similar situation and asked the IEEE Access editorial office. Here's the response excerpt:

> (...) Please note that it's a good practice to resubmit at your earliest convenience, though the system is showing your resubmission to be due on `[my rejection date + 1 year - 1 day]`.

But I don't know if that applies to every case, so I'd simply ask them. They replied me within a day or so.